# How do I connect to a Sybase Server using Python 3.1 in Windows 7?

Tags: python, sql, windows-7, sybase, python-3.1

I have thoroughly researched into this topic and I cannot get anything to work.
I have tried to run modules I downloaded from this webpage:

http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/download.html

The problem is that the latest releases are only supported up to Windows XP Pro.
Can anyone help by giving me and many other users in the future some clear installation instructions of what modules they used to get this running?

Potential modules include sybpydb, Sybase, pyodbc?

*SIDE NOTE*: Ideally, I'm looking for syntax like this

```
import Sybase

db = Sybase.connect('server','name','pass','database')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("sql statement")
list1 = c.fetchall()

print list1
```